# Changing connection interval for BLE on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I am writing a Python program to have a Raspberry Pi (Raspberry Pi 4 Model B) act as a central unit to receive data through BLE. I want to decrease the power used by the peripheral unit (I'm using an STM32WB15 chip as the peripheral) by decreasing the connection interval to as close to the maximum connection interval of 4 seconds as possible. I'm not sure how exactly I should go about doing this and would appreciate any help. Has anyone done anything similar and know how I should go about changing the connection interval for a BLE connection in Python on a Raspberry Pi?

I tried looking for Bluetooth libraries (I've looked at Bleak and Bluez) that allows be access to changing connection parameters but didn't have any luck.